# Percentage of two values returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, percentage

Same as yesterdays question which has been answered successfully but different problem. I have two values, 1 and 0 for which I need to calculate the percent change. Based on this website http://www.percent-change.com/index.php?y1=1&y2=0 the percent change between 1 and 0 is -100%. Based on the suggested formula which is (((y2- y1))/ y1) my code looks like this.

```
DefinedYearVSPriorYearIndividual = ((( CTEDefinedYear.IndividualCases - CTEPreviousYear.IndividualCasesLastYear ))
                                              / ( CTEPreviousYear.IndividualCasesLastYear ) ) * 100
```

which returns NULL.

The two numbers are

```
CTEDefinedYear.IndividualCases = 1
CTEPreviousYear.IndividualCasesLastYear = 0
```

The desired result should be -100%.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You simply divide to zero.. you need to switch your variables..

Comment: Any value could be 0, I need support for 0's. I've also tried changing the 0 to another number and it still returns NULL.

Comment: then you need to write an if block and check if the divider is zero you need to return your what you need to return

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
Declare @y1 as int =1; 
Declare @y2 as int =0;
 select (((@y2- @y1))/ @y1)*100
```

Output is -100. You missed the *100 part.

Comment: I didn't miss the *100 part, it's in the code. The code as you have it works but when I add into my code it returns NULL. Could you edit the code based on my code please so I can try again because I seem to be returning null.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, You switched variables. attached formula is right one.

```
select ((0 - 1) / 1)*100;
```

But you used `select  ((1 - 0) / 0)*100;`

so, you will get an error:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle 0 in the division side, with CASE logic, to avoid divide by zero error.

```
DECLARE @CTEDefinedYear_IndividualCases INT = 1
DECLARE @CTEPreviousYear_IndividualCasesLastYear INT = 0

SELECT ((@CTEDefinedYear_IndividualCases - @CTEPreviousYear_IndividualCasesLastYear) / (CASE WHEN @CTEPreviousYear_IndividualCasesLastYear = 0 THEN 1 ELSE @CTEPreviousYear_IndividualCasesLastYear END)) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this code.

```
DefinedYearVSPriorYearIndividual =  ISNULL(100.0 * 
                                        (ISNULL(CTEDefinedYear.IndividualCases,0) 
                                        - ISNULL(CTEPreviousYear.IndividualCasesLastYear,0)) 
                                        / NULLIF(CTEPreviousYear.IndividualCasesLastYear,0),0)
```